# codeigniter Passing variable to another function in same controller got warning illegal string even variable passed correctly

Tags: php, codeigniter

I tried to passing variable `$passdataqty` with array inside from `public function inputstokkeluarSedia()` to `public function public function check_inputqty($passdataqty)` all this function located in 1 controller

with this code :

```
public function inputstokkeluarSedia()
{
 ...
 $passdataqty = array(
   'id_sedia' => $this->input->post('id_sedia'),
   'stock_keluar' => $this->input->post('qtyinput'),
   'jenis_dok' => $this->input->post('jenisdok'),            
  );
$this->check_inputqty($passdataqty);
...
}

public function check_inputqty($passdataqty)
{
 ...
 $id_sedia = $passdataqty['id_sedia'];
 $jenis_dok = $passdataqty['jenis_dok'];
 $stock_keluar = $passdataqty['stock_keluar'];
 $this->db->select('stock_rincian');

 $this->db->from('persediaan_stock_rincian');
 $this->db->where('id_sedia', $id_sedia);
 $this->db->where('jenis_dok', $jenis_dok);
 $query = $this->db->get()->row()->stock_rincian;
    
 if ($stock_keluar > $query) {
      $this->form_validation->set_message('check_inputqty', 'Kuantitas barang yang ingin 
      dikeluarkan melebihi jumlah stok yg ada!');
      return FALSE;
 } else {
      return TRUE;
 }
}
```

the code work well but im getting this warning.

> Message: Illegal string offset 'id_sedia'

> Message: Illegal string offset 'jenis_dok'

> Message: Illegal string offset 'stock_keluar'

> Message: Trying to get property 'stock_rincian' of non-object

the question is : how to solve this warning even the code works ? can someone explain why this warning shows up ?

Comment: Where in your code are you calling `->check_inputqty($passdataqty)`? Where are you retrieving `$passdataqty` from the `inputstokkeluarSedia()` method? (those lines are not shown in your code)

Comment: did you get value in `$id_sedia` ?

Comment: @verjas  sorry i forgot to type the variable, it update now in `function inputstokkeluarsedia()` , @DevsiOdedra yes i get the value when i tried with var_dump the value is : `string(2) "13"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with `$this->db->get()->row()->stock_rincian`
Instead use:

```
if($this->db->get()->num_rows()>0){
    return True;
}else{
    return False;
}
```

Comment: $query in my if statement is dynamic not always 0, so i need that variable passed from `public function inputstokkeluarSedia()`

Comment: the problem is with this line '$this->db->get()->row()->stock_rincia' you can not use  stock_rincia  after row()-> you have to get the row_array() result in a varible then compare using if condition

Comment: okay, Im getting result now after add row_array, thx.